# How to retrieve values from a website(URL) from android app?

Tags: android

How to retrieve the values present in a website?

here is my java code,

```
 public void String[] receive()
    {
    String url="http://shrib.com/content123";

    DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
    try {
        HttpResponse execute = client.execute(httpGet);
        InputStream content = execute.getEntity().getContent();

        BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(content));
        String s[];
        s=buffer.readLine().split(" ");
        return s;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
  }
```

When this code is run, the application is stopped

in AndroidManifest.xml

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

is also added..

Yet the code fails.

eg) consider the values in www.shrib.com/content123

```
 10 20 30 40
```

each separated by space 
so using split(" ") function, to separate the values...

My stacktrace exception

```
  android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException

at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1156)

     at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:385)
     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:137)
     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
     at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:365)
     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:587)
     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:511)
     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:489)
     at vehicle_monitor25.com.example.Main1.receive(Main1.java:182)
     at vehicle_monitor25.com.example.Main1.onCreate(Main1.java:58)
     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5343)
     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1088) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2331)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2429)



       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:828)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:644)
       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

     java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{vehicle_monitor25.com.example/vehicle_monitor25.com.example.Main1}: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2377)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2429)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1342)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
    ... 11 more
```

After executing asyntask

```
    public class Main1 extends Activity{
        TextView tv1,tv2,tv3,tv4;
        Button bt1,bt2;
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main1);

        int t1,t2,t3,t4;
        String s1,s2,s3,s4;
        t1=10;
        tv1=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv1);
        tv1.setText("10");
        new NetworkOperation.execute("");

    }
    public class NetworkOperation extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
    {

     protected String[] doInBackground(String... params) {
                //Do your network operation here
         String url = "http://www.shrib.com/sridhar123";

            DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
         HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
         try {
             HttpResponse execute = client.execute(httpGet);
             InputStream content = execute.getEntity().getContent();

             BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(
                     new InputStreamReader(content));
             String s[];
             s=buffer.readLine().split(" ");
             return s;
         } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
         }

                return null;
            }

            protected void onPostExecute(String[] result) {

                tv1.setText(result[0]);

            }

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
            }

            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return null;
            }
    }
}
```

NetworkOperation cannot be resolved to type error

Comment: "Yet the code fails" - how exactly does it fail? The app crashes, or there is just no data coming from the server? Please be more explicit.

Comment: says, the application has stopped

Comment: NetworkOnMainThreadException?
You should execute your Network calls in a separate thread, think about using an AsyncTask.

Comment: The please post the stacktrace of the exception.

Comment: yes  NetworkOnMainThreadException

Comment: Stacktrace of the exception posted

Answer (score -1):

Use an asyncTask thread to implement network operation.

```
class NetworkOperation extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
{
 @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            //Do your network operation here
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
        }
}
```

to call this class,use

```
new NetworkOperation.execute();
```

Comment: You should never use asynctask for networking because it is not parallel by default (each new task will wait for not completed). Developer in this case have to run asynctask on executor or use another threading mechanism.

Comment: Then should I use, NetworkOperation.executeOnExecutor()?

Comment: NetworkOperation.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR); will help.